# iOS system native share method specify app with audio or video

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to make a function of iOS system native share.This is easy,but I want to specify app with sharing.

Now I mean show 'GarageBand' app every time in bottom activity controller sheet.And I can share audio to 'GargeBand' app. So what can I do?

I want this 'GarageBand' app show every time in call system native share.

Here are some attempts I made.

```py
NSString * const  garagebandBundleId = @"com.apple.mobilegarageband";

    BOOL isAvailable = [SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:garagebandBundleId];
    if (isAvailable == NO) {
        return;
    }

    SLComposeViewController *composeVC = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:garagebandBundleId];
    BOOL isText = [composeVC setInitialText:@"test ring"];
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSURL *audioUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
    BOOL isAudioUrl = [composeVC addURL:audioUrl];

    [self presentViewController:composeVC animated:YES completion:^{
        NSLog(@"log-come share");
    }];

    [composeVC setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {
        if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled) {
            NSLog(@"cancel share");
        }else if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultDone) {
            NSLog(@"share done");
        }

        //  dismiss the Tweet Sheet
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
                NSLog(@"Sheet has been dismissed.");
            }];
        });
    }];
```

I use above code with app share  extension id.But I get error.

```py
[core] Sheet not being presented, calling premature completion
```

So I guess 'Garageband' app share extension id is wrong.

I description is over.What can I do?

Thanke you your help.